# Tracking data sync to salesforce from a transactional send

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send, email-tracking

I have a "Triggered Send" type data extension in the Salesforce Data Extensions folder and my transactional sends are being successfully logged there (I can see those when clicking on individual Subscriber records)

1. My subscriber key = Contact ID from Salesforce (18 Digit)
2. I have a proper SF Connector set-up with a tracking user

What should I add in my config to make the send visible on the Salesforce record (Contact)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only triggered sends initiated from the Sales/Service cloud generate the IER in SFDC. This is explained in the following [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_track_triggered_sends.htm&type=5):

> Triggered sends created in the Sales or Service Cloud return tracking from the Marketing Cloud to the Sales or Service Cloud. Triggered sends created in the Marketing Cloud do not return tracking to the Sales or Service Cloud. For example, an API call into the Marketing Cloud does not return tracking to the Sales or Service Cloud.